# Microshift levers with Ultegra brakes

Tags: brakes, shimano, rim-brake

I have a 2012 Felt F95 (as shown at: http://www.wiggle.co.uk/felt-f95-2012/) and I wanted to upgrade the brakes to Shimano Ultegras.  I was wondering if these are compatible together.

Comment: Don't bother.  You'll get a phenomenal improvement by changing out the brake pads for decent ones like kool-stop, making sure the wheels are true and the rims are clean, replacing the inner and outer brake cables, and lubricating the brake lever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe all drop-bar road bike brake levers designed for caliper brakes use the same cable pull ratio, so yes you can fit Ultegra calipers.

Personal opinion follows ...

I'm not a fan of installing individual components of a level many steps up from the rest of the components on a bike. You may not see the full performance benefits of the high-level calipers because the lower level Microshift levers will be the limiting factor.

The Felt F95 has no-brand calipers I believe (at least the 2017 does, your link to Wiggle does not work), so even Claris or Sora level are going to be better. You may as well save a little money.

Comment: New-ish Shimano "Super SLR" brakes have different cable pull from standard. They have been used successfully with normal brake levers, but if there's a choice it's probably better to get something actually compatible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think I am going to take your advice and go for the Soras